# React-Helmet not updating meta and title in SSR application

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, server-side-rendering, meta-tags, react-helmet

I have updated this to use react-helmet-async in place of react-helmet.

I have a React application that has implemented server side rendering.  I am following the steps on this site: [Documentation for react-helmet-async](https://openbase.com/js/react-helmet-async/documentation), to implement the react-helmet-async functionality to dynamically assign meta and title.  I am using a provider and have added the Helmet component to the App.js and the learnerSetupContainer.js scripts. When I look at the source code for both these pages I can that the title and meta for the home page is properly updated but the learnerSetupContainer is not being updated and is showing the same title and meta as the home page,

```
          <title data-rh="true" itemprop="name" lang="en">Welcome to our Homepage</title>
          <meta data-rh="true" name="description" content="Teach Learn Game"/><meta data-rh="true" name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no"/>
```

I see other stackoverflow questions that say, "It's not documented in the readme, but you have to add data-react-helmet="true" to your meta tags that you want to replace with react-helmet."  I tried adding this string but there was no change.  Maybe I am not adding correctly.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Below is the code I am using:

template.js

```
export default ({ markup, helmet , css }) => {
  return `<!doctype html>
      <html ${helmet.htmlAttributes.toString()}>
        <head>
        <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-1234567-9">
        </script>
        <script>
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag('js', new Date());

          gtag('config', 'UA-123456789-9');
        </script>
        <script data-ad-client="ca-pub-123456789012345" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="msvalidate.01" content="1234567890ASDFGHJJ" />
          <meta name="google-site-verification" content="1234567890ASDFGHJKL" />

          ${helmet.title.toString()}
          ${helmet.meta.toString()}
          ${helmet.link.toString()}

          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
          <style>
              a{
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #bb4d00
              }
          </style>
        </head>
        <body ${helmet.bodyAttributes.toString()}>
          <div id="root">${markup}</div>
          <style id="jss-server-side">${css}</style>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>  

        </body>
      </html>`;
};
```

express.js (only code relevant to react-helmet)

```
import {Helmet, HelmetProvider} from "react-helmet-async";

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
  const context = {};
  const helmetContext = {};
  const markup = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
  //const markup = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
    sheets.collect( 
      <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <HelmetProvider context = {helmetContext}>
           <MainRouter />
          </HelmetProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </StaticRouter>
    )
  );
  const {helmet} = helmetContext;
  console.log ("Express - markup = ", markup);
  console.log ("Express - helmet = ", helmet);
  console.log ("Express - helmetContext = ", helmetContext);
  console.log ("Express - helmet.title.toString() = ", helmet.title.toString());
  console.log ("Express - helmet.meta.toString() = ", helmet.meta.toString());
  if (context.url) {
    return res.redirect(303, context.url);
  }
  const css = sheets.toString();
  res.status(200).send(
    Template({
      markup: markup,
      helmet: helmet,
      css: css,
    })
  );
});
```

App.js (only code relevant to react-helmet)

```
import {Helmet, HelmetProvider} from "react-helmet-async";

return (
    <>

  <React.StrictMode>

  <BrowserRouter>
  <ThemeProvider theme={responsivetheme}>
        <SpeechDataProvider>
            <CriteriaProvider>
                <RandomOptionsProvider>
                  <HelmetProvider>
                    <MainRouter />
                  </HelmetProvider>
                </RandomOptionsProvider>
            </CriteriaProvider>
          </SpeechDataProvider>
  </ThemeProvider>
  </BrowserRouter>

  </React.StrictMode>
  </>
  );
```

MenuRouter.js (only code relevant to react-helmet)

```
import {Helmet, HelmetProvider} from "react-helmet-async";

  return (
    <div>
    <Helmet
      data-rh="true"
      htmlAttributes={{lang: "en", amp: undefined}} // amp takes no value
      //titleTemplate="%s | React App"
      titleAttributes={{itemprop: "name", lang: "en"}}
      title="Welcome to our Homepage"
      meta={[
        {name: "description", content: "Teach Learn Game"},
        {name: "viewport", content: "minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no"},
      ]}
    /> 
    </div>
```

learnerSetupContainer.js (only code relevant to react-helmet)

```
import {Helmet, HelmetProvider} from "react-helmet-async";

  return (
   <>
    <div>
    <Helmet>
        <title data-rh="true">Welcome to our Learner Setup Page </title>
        <meta data-rh="true" name="description" content="Game Options: Vocabulary, Math, History and Geography" />
        <meta data-rh="true" name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no" />
      </Helmet>
    </div>

   </>
```

Comment: This question has been updated to implement react-helmet-async in place of react-helmet

Comment: I was using,  "view page source" to look at the meta tags. Per a previous Stack Overflow question, I am using the Developer Tools->Elements options.  As stated in a previous questions:                                                                     
 You cannot inspect meta tags from html source, because:
html source is static content that javascript cannot touch
helmet will create meta tags for you after react javascript has been executed
If you want to check meta tags:
Use "Element" tab in developer tool instead of inspect source
Use console to check if meta tags exists: